# \printbibliography does not work

Tags: bibliographies

I have before the beginning of the document `\addbibresource{references.bib}` and at the end of it `\printbibliography`.

The references have this format :

```
@ARTICLE{2015MNRAS.452.1089P,
   author = {{Porth}, O. and {Komissarov}, S.~S.},
    title = "{Causality and stability of cosmic jets}",
  journal = {\mnras},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {1408.3318},
 primaryClass = "astro-ph.HE",
 keywords = {instabilities, MHD, relativistic processes, stars: jets, galaxies: active, galaxies: jets},
     year = 2015,
    month = sep,
   volume = 452,
    pages = {1089-1104},
      doi = {10.1093/mnras/stv1295},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015MNRAS.452.1089P},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
```

No error, but doesn't print a thing.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

 \usepackage[a4paper,width=160mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]
{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{esint}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}


\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\graphicspath{{Images/}}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{#1}}}}



\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}

\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Αλληλεπίδραση αστροφυσικών πιδάκων πλάσματος με το περιβάλλον 
τους}
\fancyfoot{}

\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\fancyfoot[LO,CE]{Κεφάλαιο \thechapter}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}



\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}



\title{Αλληλεπίδραση πιδάκων με το περιβάλλον τους}

\date{Oκτώβριος 2017}




\begin{document}

"

End: "


\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. By default only works that are actually cited in the text are included in the reference list, so you need e.g. `\autocite{2015MNRAS.452.1089P}` somewhere. Or if you want to add everything in the `.bib` file to the reference list without citing them, `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: And did you remember run biber and recompile afterwards? Btw: it us always a good idea to post a full minimal example, not just a sniplet, gives us a better idea of what you are doing.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. \notice{*} , where should i post that?

Comment: @daleif I think the problem is that i haven't cited them on my text.

Comment: Anywhere in the document would do I think, for example right before `\printbibliography`. And of course, you need to run `biber` as daleif mentioned above.

Comment: For help on running Biber, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Comment: Now you probably see why we always ask for a full minimal example. Hope it was as simple as this.

Comment: @daleif But where should I post \notice{*}

Comment: As other people mention, somewhere in your doc. I usually place it right before where the bibliography will be printed. But it does not matter. It is a comnand that needs to write something to the aux.

Comment: @daleif " \nocite{*}
\printbibliography" doesn't work :( God, and I have to fix this today.

Comment: Did you run biber?? Else, bow your head and make that minimal example, it does not need to be your full document, just so we can see what you are working with. But check the biber stuff first. Latex does not run biber automatically, some editors do, but most does not.

Comment: @daleif No, what is biber? How do I run this? (Posting right now)

Comment: So you're using biblatex and not knowing how it actually works? Might be an idea if you too a look in the biblatex manual. Now we also need to know which editor you are using. I tend to tell users to always also know how to do stuff from the command line, because then they are independent of the editor us they one day find up in a pickle.

Comment: @daleif I m windows user, and i use TeXworks.

Comment: I haven't uses tw for a while. You might be able to choose biber from the drop down next to the green button. Choose it, run, which the default again and run it twice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67721/discussion-between-billy-matlock-and-daleif).

Answer (score 2):

To bring this to an end I created the following MWE `mwe.tex` which can be compiled without errors (See important code changings marked with `<=======`):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{2015MNRAS.452.1089P,
   author = {{Porth}, O. and {Komissarov}, S.~S.},
    title = "{Causality and stability of cosmic jets}",
  journal = {\mnras},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {1408.3318},
 primaryClass = "astro-ph.HE",
 keywords = {instabilities, MHD, relativistic processes, stars: jets, 
             galaxies: active, galaxies: jets},
     year = 2015,
    month = sep,
   volume = 452,
    pages = {1089-1104},
      doi = {10.1093/mnras/stv1295},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015MNRAS.452.1089P},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage[%
  a4paper,width=160mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext} % <========to write dummy text in document ======

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % <===== to use bib file created with filecontents

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\mnras}{Very Important Journal} % <=========================

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Αλληλεπίδραση αστροφυσικών πιδάκων πλάσματος με το περιβάλλον 
τους}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,CE]{Κεφάλαιο \thechapter}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\title{Αλληλεπίδραση πιδάκων με το περιβάλλον τους}
\date{Oκτώβριος 2017}


\begin{document}

\blindtext
\nocite{*} or \cite{2015MNRAS.452.1089P} % <============================

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Because you have the line `journal = {\mnras},` in your bib file you need to define macro `\mnras` like I did:

```
\newcommand{\mnras}{Very Important Journal}
```

or just delete the macro in your bib file ...

To get an bibliography you need to use

```
\nocite{*} or \cite{2015MNRAS.452.1089P}
```

`\nocite{*}` prints **all** not cited bib entrys in your bibliography, with `\cite{key}` you can cite bib entry `key` in your document. You need at last one or more `\cite` or `\nocites{*}` to get a bibliography printed!

The given MWE results in the following bibliography (page 2):

[image: bibliography]

If you have problems to get your editor to use biber use the terminal/console instead.  Type the 4 commands in your terminal:

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
biber mwe.aux
pdflatex mwe.tex
pdflatex mwe.tex
```